# How to set onClick events in React from the server

Tags: html, reactjs, parsing, dynamically-generated, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

On the server I programmatically set as to what onClick event should be attached to what function in React, writing "onClick={function_name}" right down into json. Unfortunately, I cannot make it work in React - the function is never fired. Has anyone any idea on the non-trivial solution?

```
import React from "react";

const fromJson = `<button onclick="morning();" class="p-8 m-2 text-lg text-white bg-red-800">Evening Greeting</button>`;

const Page = () => {

  const morning = (event) => {
    alert("Good morning!", event.target);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        // Traditional way, not my case
        <button onClick={morning} class="p-8 m-2 text-lg text-white bg-red-800">
          Morning Very Greeting
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
       // The closest solution, which doesn't work out either.
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: fromJson }} />
      </div>
     </>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Comment: Frankly: Don't do that. Put structured data in the JSON, not HTML. Then use JSX to render it.

Comment: Which part of the code snippet is the question, the individual buttons with `{morning or evening}` or the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` button?

Comment: @Tom Following your comment, I specified my question (see P.S., please)

Comment: @Quentin I wish I could. What function should fire what button is calculated. I am not sure whether React can stand intense calculations well. Thanks.